# Chat client only printing 1 line at a time

Tags: java, sockets

I am writing a multithread chat server/client, I have been using SocketTest V 3 to test the server and it seems to be working fine but the client I have written only updates in the console when I write a new line, I am using my own client up against the socket test, and the socket updates every time something is written but my client does not

```
public class clientV2 {


public static final int PORT = 5019;
public static InetAddress host;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try {
        host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        Socket socket = new Socket(host, PORT);

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        Scanner inputFromServer = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());

        PrintWriter outputToServer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

        while(true) {
            if(inputFromServer.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(inputFromServer.nextLine());
            }

            String input = in.nextLine();
            outputToServer.println(input);
            outputToServer.flush();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your client calls [`nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) on its scanner, and this method, as it names indicates, returns the next line. So your client can't print anything until the complete next line is available.

Here's what the javadoc says about `nextLine()`:

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that
>   was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line,
>   excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the
>   beginning of the next line.
>
> Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a
>   line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line
>   to skip if no line separators are present.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `System.out.println(inputFromServer.nextLine());` does exactly that. It waits for a full line and then prints that out. It will not print partial lines.

If the output is missing more than just the last partial line (line-break to line-break; line wraps don't count), look for the buffers along the way.

You can use an [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) to read single characters from the input stream (which is a byte stream). You can specify the charset in the constructor.

```
InputStreamReader inputFromServer = 
  new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");

System.out.print((char) inputFromServer.read());
```

Comment: i need it to print everytime anonter client writes something, how can i do this